Cannot find pdflatex.fmt
I installed texlive from the iso image.
I am trying to convert an epub to pdf using:
pandoc  -f epub  -o my.pdf my.epub
However, I get:
Error producing PDF.
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
I can't find the format file `pdflatex.fmt'
Any idea what I can do?
The file exists
/opt/texlive/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt
Thank you.

Can you run pdflatex from the same prompt you are running pandoc?

pdflatex --version
pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024)
kpathsea version 6.4.0
Copyright 2024 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.43; using libpng 1.6.43
Compiled with zlib 1.3.1; using zlib 1.3.1
Compiled with xpdf version 4.04

and which pdflatex? Can you run pdflatex on a simple doc? Like \documentclass{article}\begin{document}hello\end{document} and it produces a PDF?

/opt/texlive/bin/x86_64-linux/pdflatex. Yes, that works. I get a textput.pdf file.

welcome! don't know much about pandoc but can you run it in verbose mode to see what it is doing? I'm assuming it is looking in the wrong place since /opt/texlive is not the default install location.

Yes. Thank you. I have a 400Kbyte log now with pandoc --verbose. Where would you like me to place it?

Am I missing an environment variable? /opt/texlive/bin/x86_64-linux is in PATH. I used /opt because I can't simply dump non-package-manager tracked files into /usr.

what do you get from kpsewhich --engine=pdftex pdflatex.fmt?

Hello, This outputs nothing.

you should ping people with @name. Apart from this: Is that in the same command line in which you could run pdflatex somefile?

@UlrikeFischer. Ok, I opened a new terminal.  set | grep TEX TEXLIVEDIR=/opt/texlive. psewhich --engine=pdftex pdflatex.fmt does not work while pdflatex "\documentclass{article}\begin{document}hello\end{document}" does

why are you adding some set and grep commands before? Simply call kpsewhich --engine=pdftex pdflatex.fmt

@UlrikeFischer Sorry, those were different commands. I just don't know how to add new lines. the kpsewich doesn't return anything.

'I used /opt because I can't simply dump non-package-manager tracked files into /usr.' That is literally what /usr/local is for. It is also why texlive's installer installs there rather than /usr/bin etc. you package manager doesn't put stuff into /usr/local. no, you shouldn't install texlive into, say /usr/texlive or /usr/lib or something, but /usr/local/texlive is fine. if you are using a system which follows the standard hierarchies, /opt is generally intended for 'blobs' i.e. non-free software. (if you are on a mac this doesn't apply as /usr will be full of blobs.)

@cfr I'm on a Linux but /usr/local is covered by the linker (binutils) so I don't wish to place things outside the native package manager there.

if I didn't want things linked in /usr/local I'd change the settings of the linker. but your distro shouldn't be linking to things in /usr/local. even if it does, though, /usr/local/texlive won't put anything there.

but you don't have to do that. only it is easier. you can install to /opt/texlive or anywhere you want to. but you should configure things properly. kpsewhich should work and your home texmf tree should be separate from the distribution one, which should use kpsewhich to find files. did you use upstream's installer? it should have done this automatically.

Hello @cfr. Yes, I used the upstream installed from the iso image. I had tried twice already.

Appending
TEXMFHOME = $SELFAUTOPARENT/
with the trailing / to:
/opt/texlive/texmf.cnf fixed the issue so far. I will ask if I come across such a thing again. Thank you everyone.

look, that may work for now, but it is not the correct solution. TEXMFHOME is for your personal customised configurations, files etc. it should be in your home directory - typically /home/<username>/texmf but probably under /Users/<username>/Library on a mac. what you have done is declare the distribution tree your personal tree. that means stuff will be found even if the databases and config is screwed up because your personal tree is searched directly by default. this is slower, but generally fine for small trees. /opt/texlive is not small. this 'solution' risks engendering chaos.

@cfr thank you for the detailed explanation. Is there any chance you know of a solution other than installing in /usr/local/? In my case, nothing critical is in /opt.

yes! it is just a question of configuration. as I ask above, how did you install? normally upstream's installer configures things automatically. the only thing you possibly have to do is modify PATH. so something went wrong if that didn't happen. did you use the install-tl script when you installed or did you get the distribution somehow else?

@cfr I used perl ./install-tl --texdir=/opt/texlive/

so then you got some choices about what to install and so on, right? and then the installer did its thing? did it report any errors? you should have a file /opt/texlive/2024/install-tl.log. That file has a bunch of settings at the top. There should be a Settings:  a few lines down. Below that there's a long list of variables. the first group all start TEX. what do they say?

@cfr unfortunately, I was dumb enough to delete the log files after installation :/

hmm. did you delete anything else? do you remember if you got the Welcome to TeX Live! message with instructions about any manual configuration needed?

I'm trying to figure out if something got screwed up in the install or whether it is installed fine and just configuration. normally, the only thing you really need to do is add the binary directory to PATH. everything else should just work. but if you deleted other things ....

@cfr I deleted nothing else but the log files. I only did find /opt/texlive -name "*.log" -delete under the assumption that log files wouldn't be further required. If I remember correctly, there were no errors during the installation. It gave me options including "I" for install which I typed it. This was the same installation procedure with both attempts.

/opt/texlive/texmf.cnf is now as follows: ---- TEXMFLOCAL = $SELFAUTOPARENT//texmf-local TEXMFSYSVAR = $SELFAUTOPARENT//texmf-var TEXMFSYSCONFIG = $SELFAUTOPARENT//texmf-config TEXMFHOME = $SELFAUTOPARENT/

if you delete or rename that file, does that help? because that is going to screw up things for sure.

@cfr, upon a quick examination, removing that file seems to fix things. For the record, this file was autogenerated and I only added the TEXMFHOME variable.

the file is autogenerated but it only contains comments by default.

In any regards, thank you very much @cfr!
